# i had created virtual keyboard in javascript which is working but i am unable to take limits and i am unable to print dy/dx properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i  had created virtual keyboard in java script which is working  but i am  unable to take limits and i am unable to print dy/dx properly in mathematical format  ,it shows clearly in virtual keyboard on click it is not taking in text area because it is taking  '$$\frac{dy}{dx} $$' has a string not escaping has a math jax format

my html code

```
<textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="query" id="textArea" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Write Your Query')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required></textarea>
```

my virtual keyboard code on click to  take that symbol

```
<td title="infinity"><button type="button" onclick="addTextAtCaret('textArea','∞')">∞</button></td> 

<td title="N-Aray summation"><button type="button" onclick="addTextAtCaret('textArea','∑')">∑</button></td>

<td title="Element of"><button type="button" onclick="addTextAtCaret('textArea','$$ \frac{dy}{dx} $$')"> $$\frac{dy}{dx} $$</button></td>
```

my java script code to take text from virtual keyboard to add it to proper position

```
    <script>
    function addTextAtCaret(textAreaId, text) {
        var textArea = document.getElementById(textAreaId);
        var cursorPosition = textArea.selectionStart;
        addTextAtCursorPosition(textArea, cursorPosition, text);
        updateCursorPosition(cursorPosition, text, textArea);
    }
    function addTextAtCursorPosition(textArea, cursorPosition, text) {
        var front = (textArea.value).substring(0, cursorPosition);
        var back = (textArea.value).substring(cursorPosition,
                textArea.value.length);
        textArea.value = front + text + back;
    }
    function updateCursorPosition(cursorPosition, text, textArea) {
        cursorPosition = cursorPosition + text.length;
        textArea.selectionStart = cursorPosition;
        textArea.selectionEnd = cursorPosition;
        textArea.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please help me ,

Answer (score 0):

I've published a JavaScript library that you can use to create a virtual math keyboard. It is intended for use together with any LaTeX typesetting library (for example MathJax or KaTeX).

GitHub repository: https://github.com/MathKeyboardEngine/MathKeyboardEngine 
Live examples: https://mathkeyboardengine.github.io

My goal was to create an easy-to-use virtual math keyboard library that is highly customizable. Let me know if you need any help.